# Nlog ${callsite-linenumber} not working properly with async methods

Tags: nlog

I am using NLog v4.4.12.

I have an async method where I must log info with line numbers being included. The problem is that if I log anything before a call to async method, line lumber is always 0. However, if I log anything after a call to async method, line number always prints correctly. Does anyone else have this issue?

Example:

```js
public class TestController : ApiController {
    private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = null, UseProxy = false })
                                                                            { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["httpTimeout"])) };
    private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public async Task DoSomething(int clientId)
    {
        logger.Info($"Here, line number is always 0");

        try
        {
            var clientBooks = new List<string>();
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            using (var response = await Client.GetAsync(new Uri(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cb"] + "books?clientId=" + clientId)))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    clientBooks = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<string>>();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Error getting books");
                }
            }

            logger.Info($"Here, line number always prints correctly");

            // Here I have some other logic ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
        }

        logger.Info($"Here, line number always prints correctly");
    }
}
```

My NLog configuration:

```
<nlog autoReload="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable name="logDirectory" value="${basedir}/Logs/${shortdate}" />
    <variable name="format" value="${longdate}|${activityid}|${logger}|${callsite-linenumber}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message}" />
    <targets>
      <target name="fileLogErrors" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/errors.txt" layout="${format}" encoding="utf-8" />
      <target name="fileLog" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/all.txt" layout="${format}" encoding="utf-8" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="fileLogErrors" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileLog" />
    </rules>
 </nlog>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the info is available (internally in .NET) when using `async` - could you try printing the full stacktrace? (`{${stracktrace}`).

Comment: @Julian Here is the stacktrace (included only ${stacktrace}|Line:${callsite-linenumber}): 


AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start => <<UpdateAttributes>b__0>d.MoveNext => AttributesBaseController.UpdateEquationAccountsInfo|Line:0 


ExecutionContext.RunInternal => MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext => <UpdateEquationAccountsInfo>d__9.MoveNext|Line:457

Comment: this is a bug/missing feature, please post an issue here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new

Comment: @Julian I opened this issue on GitHub. [link](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2382)

Answer (score 0):

NLog ver. 4.5 resolves this issue: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2382